# oracle apex 18 capture insert update and delete events before or after

Tags: oracle-apex

I am working in oracle apex 18.2 , i have some requirements regarding IUD triggers on table , i am good in creating database level triggers but i want to Process at Apex level , For example if i have below Trigger on database level

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER xx_stu_transfer_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON S_STU_TRANSFERS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Flags are booleans and can be used in any branching construct.
  CASE
    WHEN INSERTING THEN
     SELECT NVL(MAX(TRANSFER_ID),0)+1 INTO :NEW.TRANSFER_ID FROM S_STU_TRANSFERS;
     :NEW.CREATION_DATE := SYSDATE;
     :NEW.CREATED_BY := nvl( v( 'APP_USER'), user) ;
    WHEN UPDATING THEN
     :NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DATE := SYSDATE;
     :NEW.LAST_UPDATED_BY  := nvl( v( 'APP_USER'), user) ;  
    ELSE
        NULL;
  END CASE;
END;
/
```

I want to Process same code in apex Process or something else where i can handle this same code. Need Suggestions with some examples

Comment: You can add Processes to an APEX page which will fire when the user clicks Save; you can also add Processes that fire for each row processed. You can control whether the Processes fire before or after the DML process.

Comment: The inserting clause of this statement is unnecessary, and the max()+1 is dangerous https://svenweller.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/sequence-and-audit-columns-with-apex-5-and-12c/

Comment: @Kemp,,, can you just explain how to identify before or after exact option..